# Opening Yii Application causes download of index.php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, yii

I recently downloaded `Yii` in my linux-ubuntu system. After extracting the files to `/var/www/vishnu/`, I went for creating the first `webapp`.

What I have done is executing `/var/www/vishnu/yii/framework/yiic webapp anyname` in my command line. It succesfully created the application under `/home/ti/anyname`

But whenever I am trying to access it, It downloads the `index.php` file instead of opening the webapp home page! Why does this happen? I tried, the following Urls..

- localhost/vishnu/anyname/ - Returns Not Found
- home/ti/anyname/index.php- Downloads the file
- home/ti/anyname/index-test.php- Downloads the file

I can see the files in `file:///home/ti/anyname/` But can't open anything. When ever I click on it, it is being downloaded! Please share your solutions if you have any...

Comment: Is other `php` file opening properly in your browser?

Comment: Yes. I have Magento files also. It works properly.

Comment: Check this link http://roshanbook.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/starting-yii-development-in-ubuntu-part-1/ here it says that you have to give 777 permission to yii_app

Comment: Giving 777 is a bad idea. But, thank you very much. I got it from that blog. I changed the command such that, the webapp will point to my localhost itslef. ie `php /var/www/vishnu/yii/framework/yiic.php webapp /var/www/vishnu/yii/anyname/` Now its working...

Comment: Do a `chmod 755 instead` , This gives the everyone read and execute permissions, but only the owner write permissions.

Comment: Check mime type for .php files

Comment: @Renku, you should add your fix as an asnwer and solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much. I got it from [this](http://roshanbook.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/starting-yii-development-in-ubuntu-part-1/) blog.

I changed the `command` such that, the webapp will point to my `localhost` itslef.

ie `php /var/www/vishnu/yii/framework/yiic.php webapp /var/www/vishnu/yii/anyname/`

Now its working... :)